# Search recursively text from each line in file using standard cmd line commands

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I have a file with variables names prepared by `grep` call.

Now I want to do following: `grep` directory recursively and search in each file each variable entries (from initially prepared file). How could I achieve it via awk/sed or any other console utility? I know how to do it with, for example, python script, but now I'd like to use pure console solution.

I am stuck on applying command to data: `awk '{ print $0}' RS="/" settings_vars.txt` Is it right? But how to call command instead of `print` line content?

Comment: you need to run the command in another subshell.

Comment: Could you post an example to make it more clear?

Comment: What do you mean by `console utility` and `console solution`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use recursive grep with `-f` option:

```
grep -rHf settings_vars.txt .
```

Options used are:

```
-f  # Read one or more newline separated patterns from file.
-H  # Always print filename headers with output lines.
-r  # Read all files under each directory, recursively, following symbolic links only 
      if they are on the command line.
```

Comment: maybe add and adapt for Regex info (depend on how to isolate the *variable entry* like a `variable=` or any `variable` with word boudary, or symply the litteral `variable` value)

Comment: Thank you! Looks like it could helps me well!

Comment: If the list of patterns are **words** to find in the file, add `-F` and `-w`